# How do you generate a previous and next button for an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, xml-parsing, media-player

I have a function with this specific array in it.

```
var elementsArray = xmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('track');
        // console.log(elementsArray);
        var arrayLength = elementsArray.length;
        var output = "<table>";
        for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
          var title = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
          var artist = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('artist')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
          var length = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('length')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
          var filename = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('filename')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
          console.log(title + '  ' + artist + '  ' + length + '  ' + filename);
          output += "<tr>";
          output += ("<td onclick='songSelect(\"" + filename + "\")'>" + title + "</td><td>" + artist + "</td>");
          output += "</tr>";
        }
```

With this array how would i generate a previous and next button to move.
http://jsfiddle.net/xbesjknL/

Comment: Please note that `elementsArray` will actually be a **live** _NodeList_ or _HTMLCollection_, which are not types of _Array_, although _array-like_

Comment: Yh I understand so how would I create a prev or next button for a HTML Collection. Thankyou @PaulS.

Answer (score 0):

Once could use a linked list or even the notion of C-like pointers that point at the prev/curr/next tracks.  But alas this is Javascript and the client side is too processing burdened.

So you could just build your own simplified idea of pointers in a cursor like object that is constantly pointing at the current track's index, the previous track's index and the next.  And you'd call the refresh method everytime the user clicks the prev or next buttons to update the cursor's pointers accordingly.

```
var cursor = { 
  prev:(elementsArray.length-1), 
  curr:0, 
  next:(1 % (elementsArray.length-1)),

  refresh: function(button){ //button is either the btnPrev or btnNext elements
    if (button.getAttribute("id") === "btnPrev") {
      old_curr = this.curr;
      this.curr = this.prev;
      if ((this.curr-1) < 0)
        this.prev = elementsArray.length-1;
      else    
        this.prev = this.curr - 1;
      this.next = old_curr;
    } else {
      old_curr = this.curr;
      this.curr = this.next;
      if ((this.curr+1) > (elementsArray.length-1))
        this.next= 0;
      else
        if (elementsArray.length === 1)
          this.next = 0;
        else
          this.next = this.curr+1;
      this.prev = old_curr;
    }
  }
};

// example usage:
cursor.refresh(btnPrev);
elementsArray[cursor.curr]; // gives the previous track, which is now the current track
```

You can even simplify this even more by just keeping track of only the current track.  Note

Comment: You may also want to do an `x | 0` on `next` for the case `elementsArray.length === 1`, i.e. `x % 0` is `NaN`

Comment: @PaulS. do you mean when next is initialized to `1 % (elementsArray.length-1)`?  When would the case be that its `x % 0`?

Comment: Consider what happens when `elementsArray.length === 1` and it's not a _btnPrev_. Furthermore, you have a syntax error; maybe you were thinking in another language - JavaScript has no `end` statement